# How to replicate a list N times in jq?

Tags: polymorphism, jq

The syntax `[...]*N` only works for strings and does not work for lists. Also, I haven't found a built-in in the manual that does this task easily.

So I had to do something like

```
[range(N)|...]|add
```

Is there an easier (or more idiomatic) way to replicate a list in jq N times?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easier way to replicate a list in jq N times?

No, apparently at least in part because the creators of jq felt that operators need not be maximally polymorphic. Consider “Javascript: The Bad Parts.”

Consider also that with compound types, the uniqueness of “the obvious meaning” is often not assured. For example, in some contexts, one might want or even expect that [1,2]*3 should yield [3,6].

Comment: Re "*apparently at least in part because the creators of jq felt that polymorphism should not in general be extended to compound types*", Except the operator in question, `*`, has polymorphism that extends to some compound types (objects). "*Multiplying two objects will merge them recursively*"

Comment: That’s why I qualified the point by saying “in general”.

Comment: How they felt is not reflected by reality. 5 out of 8 operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `//` and assignments; but not `/`, `%` and comparisons) are documented to work on compound some types. In general, operators work on some compound types more often than not. And again, it's disingenuous to argue that `*` doesn't work on arrays when because the designers frowned upon operators working on compound types in general when `*` works on compound types.

Comment: jq has six types, and there are therefore 36 possible restrictions of  `_ * _` .  jq has two compound types, and the number of possible restrictions of `_*_` involving at least one compound type is thus 20.  Of these 20 possibilities, only one (`object * object`) is actually defined, and it does not extend any of the other defined restrictions.

Comment: So? That doesn't contradict or even relate to anything I've said

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're looking for does not exist. Your best bet would be to define a function to repeat the value for a reusable option.

```
def repeat($n):
    . as $val | range($n) | $val;
```

In your case, to create an array which repeats the contents of another array N times, you could use the above to do this:

```
[repeat($N)[]]
```

for some number `$N`.